# Combobox ItemTemplate dont accept click

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, click, itemtemplate

I made a Usercontrol with a Combobox with itemTemplate. I set a an event trigger for click on Item. but its not work completely.  it dosent accept the click. around the template or empty place before my text.
this is my code

```
        <Combobox>
        <Combobox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="25" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Command}"
                                                    CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}" />
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <Image Height="20" Width="25" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Combobox.ItemTemplate>
    </Combobox>
```

it is a usercontrol that binds to a list of object contains Command and commandparameter, on click on each item one command should be raised.

Comment: how can you tell it does not accept your clicks ? firstly do the following :
set Grid Background="Transparent" , with no background color even transparent the hit testing is disregarded.

Comment: I Set the Background={x:Null} but nothing. the click is perform but in some place of item it not work

Comment: not {x:Null}  i said "Transparent"

Comment: thanks, it comes better. but its not perform near the boder of item.

Answer (score 1):

Visual elements need to be assigned a brush in order for hit testing to take place. 
(I did say IsHitTestVisibile so you wouldn't confuse the two).

You can do the following above your ItemTemplate in the Container that hosts it like so :

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}"> <!-- Or based on any other ComboboxItem style you have-->
             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
         </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

FYI : IsHitTestVisibile is a flag stating that even if a Hit test did pass you can choose to disregard it.

Comment: Are you sure that didn't solve your issue ? 
but the background on the grid only partially solved it ..?

Comment: @Avrohom maybe something else is observing the click even. use snoop to figure out what your clicking

Comment: @eran_oztap Not sure about a MouseLeftButtonUp event. I was trying with a MouseLeftButtonDown an could not catch it. Seems to be handled at the Preview level.

Comment: @Avrohom use PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with `SelectionChanged` event of `ListBox`? 
You could bind to that.

DataTemplate is for the `data` not for `UI` events. You use data-templates to tell WPF how you want to display data. At most you could have `DataTriggers` (which is again belong to `data`).

If you want to trap the click event on `items`, use `ItemContainerStyle`. The `ItemContainerStyle` is for styling the container of dataitem, which is `ListBoxItem` in this case.

Something of this sort might help:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
<Style.Triggers>
   <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
  </EventTrigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: that wouldn't work ... an interaction trigger is not that kind of trigger ..
have you even tried it out before posting this ?

Comment: thanks, but <i:EventTrigger> can not be set on <Style.Triggers>

Comment: Ok, I admit, I've not tried it out. But, you get the jest of it. It was for illustration. I'll try to resolve it.